# Capybara doesn't wait till the end of file upload

Tags: ruby, capybara

I am writing a script with Ruby and Capybara. This script should upload a file and once the file was uploaded, the script should click "Save" button.
I succeeded to make the file starts to upload but after several seconds the script just stops. In the end, the file is not uploaded and I need to start everything from the scratch.

There is a button "Save" on the page that stays disabled until the file is uploaded. So I tried to use its state as an indicator. But Capybara doesn't recognize it.

My Code:

```
upload_btn = browser.all(:element, 'span', text: 'Upload')
browser.attach_file($app_path) do
  upload_btn[0].click
end
browser.has_button?('Save', wait: 200)
browser.click_on('Save')
```

How the UI of the page looks like(sorry for the screenshot):
[image]

I assume it doesn't work because it's not `button` but `material-button` and Capybara doesn't recognize this element. Using classes/ids is not the best idea since all the classes are dynamic and I cannot count on it

Could you advise what could be done here? Or how I make capybara wait till this button will be disabled?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the turnaround was maybe not the most professional but at least it worked and I can automate some things now.

Basically, I used `has_button?` to make my script wait till the APK file will be uploaded. 200sec is enough for file upload (statistically).
In the end, the script makes a pause but I decided to add `sleep 3` in the end just to be on the safe side.

Here is the function which uploads APK for me. Maybe someone will need it

```
 def create_release
   puts('Create release and upload APK')
   browser.find(:element, 'div', role: 'menuitem', text: 'Production').click
   create_release_btn = browser.all(:button, text: 'Create new release')
   create_release_btn[0].click

   #OPT out
   browser.click_button('Manage preferences', wait: 200)
   sleep 2
   browser.choose('Opt out of app signing by Google Play')
   browser.click_button('Update', wait: 100)
   sleep 3
   op_out_btn = browser.all(:button, text: 'Opt out', wait: 500)
   op_out_btn[0].click
   sleep 4

   #File upload part and saving
   upload_btn = browser.all(:element, 'span', text: 'Upload')
   browser.attach_file($app_path) do
     upload_btn[0].click
   end
   save_btn = browser.all(:element, 'material-button', text: 'Save', disabled: false, wait: 200)
   browser.has_button?(save_btn, disabled: false, wait: 200)
   button_test = browser.all(:button, text: 'Save', wait: 100)
   button_test[0].click

   sleep 3
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Now that OP has posted their full method, for anyone coming along to this question later PLEASE don't write Capybara code like in the currently accepted answer.

1. Don't use `all` when all you care about is the `first` element
2. Don't use the :element selector type when you don't really need it
3. Don't use the predicate methods just for waiting
4. Prefer an expectation/assertion over just sleeping

That boils down to something more like

```
def create_release
  puts('Create release and upload APK')
  browser.find('div[role="menuitem"]', text: 'Production').click
  browser.first(:button, 'Create new release').click

  #OPT out
  browser.click_button('Manage preferences', wait: 200) # 200 seems like a really long max wait time here
  browser.choose('Opt out of app signing by Google Play')
  browser.click_button('Update', wait: 100) # again - seems really long

  browser.first(:button, 'Opt out', wait: 500).click # and again

  #File upload part and saving
  browser.attach_file($app_path) do
    browser.first('span', text: 'Upload').click
  end

  expect(browser).to have_selector(:element, 'material-button', text: 'Save', disabled: false, wait: 200)
  browser.first(:button, 'Save', wait: 300).click

  expect(browser).to ... # whatever change clicking the button triggers 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `is_disabled` class and `disabled` attribute are removed when the button becomes active then you could use any of the following (assuming 200 seconds is enough for the upload to complete)

```
find('material-button:not([disabled])', text: 'Save', wait: 200).click
find('material-button:not(.is_disabled)', text: 'Save', wait:200).click
find('material-button', class: '^is_disabled', text: 'Save', wait: 200).click # The ^ in front of the class name indicates to negate
```

If the `debug-id` is available and stable then you can skip the `text` option, which will be more efficient

```
find("material-button[debug-id='save-button']:not([disabled])", wait:200).click
```

One final option would be to use the Capybara :element selector type

```
find(:element, 'material-design', 'debug-id': 'save-button', disabled: false, wait: 200).click
find(:element, 'material-design', disabled: false, text: 'Save', wait: 200).click
```

Comment: Not that I am an expert but is the wait actually necessary? It seems that (according to my reading) capybara will auto wait on find until the match occurs.

Comment: @engineersmnky By default Capybara will wait up to `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` for a condition to be met.  That defaults to 2 seconds, and depending on the hardware being used for testing would generally be set somewhere in the 1-5 second range.  Based on the original post I assume the upload isn't finishing within that range so included the `wait` option.  It is a maximum wait time so when the condition is met it would continue on (ie. it wouldn't wait the full 200) so worst case is it delays failure cases if/when the upload actually fails.

Comment: Perfect. Consider me edified. I appreciate the clarification and now I know should I have need to utilize capybara in the future.

Comment: The turnaround for me was a bit different from what you wrote. But the closest was the last variant you proposed. I will post the solution now below. Thank you for your advices, guys!